# Apache redirectMatch, add query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I'm redirecting from a subfolder to a subdomain. This is working fine, but I'd like to append a query string at the end of my url to track how many people have been redirected.

```
RewriteRule ^/my-folder/(.*)$ https://subdomain.example.com/?ref=my_ref [R=302,L]
```

The above should be working according to [this article](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/), but it doesn't.

It just redirects me to `https://subdomain.example.com/`

How do I add `?ref=my_ref` during a redirect?

Edit:
The full .htaccess

```
#to remove old /forum/topic and keep /topic
RewriteRule ^forum/topic/(.*)$ /topic/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

### Rewrites Engine
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map)(\?|$) /404error.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^/my-folder/(.*)/?$ https://subdomain.example.com/?ref=$1 [R=302,L,NC]      

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples could you please try following. I hope you are looking for this one. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
### Rewrites Engine
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map)(\?|$) /404error.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^my-folder/(.*)/?$ https://subdomain.example.com/?ref=your_string [R=302,L,NC]      

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```